# Windows Phone 8 Share content in Web Browser upon javascript call

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8

I got a HTML pages that I can navigate between the content using jQuery that which have a share button. they're using it in iOS and iPhone to share the content using email and other social media apps available in the platform.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to achieve and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Handle  a Browser Navigating event. In the event you will get the tag from href. For example if you make a mailto tag in href you will get that.

```
<a href='mailto:MyMailToValue'>Share</a>
```

Just do some string manipulation to get the value from the mailto eg: MyMailToValue. 
And now you have a Tag for which you can have any string that you want to share.